# WPF datagrid: how to replace null values with 'n/a' automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid biding to nullable properties. For null values in DataGridTextColumn, instead of showing empty cell, I'd like to display 'n/a'. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible by using the `Converter` property of binding. But if cells are empty only because of null values, you can use the `TargetNullValue` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) Property to set a default text if the binding returns null.

**SAMPLE**

```
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeText" Binding="{Binding 
                         MyNullabeProperty,TargetNullValue=N/A}"/>
```

Comment: I want to apply this to the whole datagrid. I tried to set <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TargetNullValue=N/A}"..., but it has no effect. Do you know why?

Comment: @miliu I know why: the ItemsSource property is bound to the existing collection which isn't null. But you can use a converter as I proposed.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the correct syntax for DataGridTextColumn with TargetNullValue!

Comment: How would I do this if my columns are being automatically generated?